# Can I get file info changes in a specified directory using FindFirstChangeNotification and FindNextChangeNofication instead of ReadDirectoryChangesW?

Tags: c++, windows, readdirectorychangesw

I want to be notified when a specified directory has any changes in its files or subdirectories. I realize the function with the following simple code segment:

```
UINT myThreadFunc(LPVOID pParam)
{
  int changeCount = 0;

  while(true)
  {
    HANDLE changeHandle = FindFirstChangeNotification(L"C:\\", TRUE, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME);
    WaitForSingleObject(changeHandle, INFINITE);
    cout<<"A modifaction has occured"<<endl;
    changeCount++;

    if (changeCount >= 10)
        break;
    if ( FindNextChangeNotification( changeHandle ) == FALSE )
        break;
  }
  bIsExit = TRUE;
  return 0;
}
```

How can I get information such as Action type or Filename without using `ReadDirectoryChangesW`?

Answer (score 1):

MSDN states :

This function does not indicate the change that satisfied the wait condition. To retrieve information about the specific change as part of the notification, use the  ReadDirectoryChangesW function.(check [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417(VS.85).aspx))